# All-in-one and lightweight management software for a software startup

Tags: project-management, issue-tracker

We are looking for a management software which suits a software startup perfectly.

We are using GitHub as version control. We do bug tracking with GitHub issues. All we want is to avoid data duplication and control everything from one place. For example, if we open a issue from GitHub and assign to someone, we don't want to create a task in another project management solution (like Zoho) manually. Management should not be an overhead and boring paperwork (e.g. syncing tasks from multiple locations by hand).

Operating system is not important. Budget not important.

We tried so far:

- **GitHub issues**, lacking business management.
- **Zoho**, heavyweight and a lot of unnecessary features.

There are dozens of alternatives in market so exhaustively searching was not feasible, then I decided to ask. I would be glad if you share your experience and recommendations. Why you choose a software over the other one etc.

Comment: The Stack Exchange sites are not aimed at open-ended or long-winded discussions. The idea is specific answers to narrowly focused questions. Please edit to list your very specific requirements and constraints. Or delete the Question to avoid down-votes and closure.

Comment: "All-in-one", "lightweight": choose one.

Comment: @Kodiologist All-in-one. If possible lightweight too. No more no less, just perfect fit, if possible.

Comment: What are you trying to manage? I see the [tag:project-management] tag, but I also see mention of GitHub :-/   Are you looking for version control, bug tracking, project planning (Gantt charts, etc), requirements tracking, all of these, more? Do you have a particular operating system in mind? Do you have a budget, or must it be free? The more information that you provide, the more that we can help you. As it stands, I have no idea what you are asking for

Comment: @Mawg We are trying to manage a software startup. We are using Github as version control. We do bug tracking with Github issues. Operating system is not important. Budget not important. All we want is to avoid data duplication and control everything from one place. For example, if we open a issue from Github and assign to someone, we don't want to create a task in another project management solution (like Zoho) manually. Management should not be an overhead and boring paperwork (E.g. Syncing tasks from multiple locations by hand).

Comment: So, it's only issue tracking then? You are not asking about IDEs, project planning, unit testing, other tools etc, etc? If so, the [tag:project-management] tag seems misleading.

Comment: @Mawg What else we could tag? I'm asking for an elegant solution where you don't need to duplicate information and you don't need to hassle with management overhead. I really can't describe that elegant solution, because I don't know what is possible what is not. That's why I'm asking you to share your experience (or best practices) about this.

Comment: To me the tag, from what you have described is clearly [tag:issue-tracker] and definitely not [tag:project-management]. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Mawg Well, problem is not limited to issue-tracking, but includes issue-tracking, so let's add issue-tracker tag while keeping project-management tag.

Comment: Then I don't quite understand what you want. Could you please update the question to state what you want over & above issue tracking?

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Pivotal Tracker, which is extremely lightweight but allows you track user stories, bugs and chores.  It has some integration with github available as well.  The interface (web based) is very clean.  They also have a decent iOS app.  There is some basic reporting.  The downside is that epics are little more than an aggregation tag.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I am the founder & CEO of [Comb](https://www.withcomb.com)

We built [Comb](https://www.withcomb.com) because we wanted a simple issue tracker that got out of our way and allowed us to go *fast*. Comb forces you to prioritize your tasks, and then assigns them in-order to team members (when they request work), according to a set of user-defined rules that allow you to spread work across the team in a way that makes sense (e.g. by skill level, difficulty of the task, subsystem, front-end/back-end, etc.).

Comb is designed to be flexible and can be customized according to your workflow. We have some built-in integrations, but you can integrate Comb to almost any system, and synchronizing Github to Comb is easy.